# Do Azure Cognitive Services containers require constant connection to the Internet?

Tags: azure, containers, azure-cognitive-services, azure-container-service

I am trying to set up a local docker container for Azure cognitive services. It seems like this particular container needs a constant internet access ([Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-container-howto#billing)).

Is there any known way to have it running locally without internet connection?

The machine I want to run the docker on doesn't have any access to the internet, it has its local network running, and I want to have that container to run on it.

Comment: No there is not. Even if it would it would violate their terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way those particular **Azure Cognitive Services containers** are setup, they require Internet connectivity to reach back to Azure for billing purposes.  One solution is to create your own containers using the Azure Cog Services you need and running them on Azure IoT Edge.

Azure IoT Edge supports extended offline operations on your IoT Edge devices, and enables offline operations on non-IoT Edge child devices too. As long as an IoT Edge device has had one opportunity to connect to IoT Hub, it and any child devices can continue to function with intermittent or no internet connection.

Here is a tutorial that show how to get up and running with cog services (computer vision) but you can sway speech and other services.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-deploy-custom-vision